# sphinx partical search and upvote words

Tags: search-engine, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx Search for a while now, but i can't get the results as i wanted. I hope someone would take some time to help me. :)

I just updated Sphinx to 2.2.10-id64-release.

What i've got: 
1 RT index with the following config:

```html
index shop_products1 {
  type = rt
  dict = keywords
  #enable_star = 1
  min_prefix_len = 3
  rt_mem_limit = 4096M

  path = /home/sphinxsearch/data/shop_products3

  morphology = stem_en, libstemmer_nl
  
  ignore_chars = U+0060, U+0027, U+0022, U+00B4

  html_strip = 1
  html_index_attrs = img=alt,title; a=title;

  preopen = 1
  inplace_enable = 1
  index_exact_words = 1

  
  rt_field = name
  rt_field = brand
  rt_field = description
  rt_field = specifications
  rt_field = tags
  rt_field = ourtags
  rt_field = searchfield
  rt_field = shop
  rt_field = category
  
  rt_field = color
  rt_field = ourcolor
  rt_field = gender
  rt_field = material

  rt_field = ean
  rt_field = sku

  rt_attr_string = ean
  rt_attr_string = sku
  rt_attr_float = price
  rt_attr_float = discount
  rt_attr_uint = shopid
  rt_attr_uint = itemid
  rt_attr_uint = deleted
  rt_attr_uint = duplicate
  rt_attr_uint = brandid
  rt_attr_uint = duplicates
  rt_attr_timestamp = updated_at
}




searchd {
 listen = 127.0.0.1:9306:mysql41
  log = /var/log/sphinxsearch/searchd.log
  workers = threads
  binlog_path = /home/sphinxsearch/rt-binlog

  #read_timeout = 10
  #client_timeout = 600
  #max_children = 0
   
  # 2 hours
  rt_flush_period = 7200
  pid_file = /var/run/searchd.pid
  
}
```

Now i have as sample the following query:

```html
SELECT 
 * , 
 weight() AS relevance, 
 COUNT(*) as count 
FROM shop_products1 
WHERE  
 price > 0  AND  
 price < 50000  AND  
 deleted <> 1  AND 
 duplicate = 0  AND 
 MATCH('(frills sieraden)') 
GROUP BY ean  
ORDER BY relevance DESC 
LIMIT 0, 40 
OPTION max_matches=50000, field_weights=(
 name=20, category=15, brand=10, description=12, searchfield=5, specifications=11, color=6, ourcolor=4, gender=5, material=4
)
```

When i run this query I get no results:

```html
Empty set (0.02 sec)

MySQL [(none)]> show meta;
+---------------+--------+
| Variable_name | Value  |
+---------------+--------+
| total         | 0      |
| total_found   | 0      |
| time          | 0.016  |
| keyword[0]    | frill  |
| docs[0]       | 619    |
| hits[0]       | 1292   |
| keyword[1]    | sierad |
| docs[1]       | 62222  |
| hits[1]       | 99708  |
+---------------+--------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

But... there are a lot of results what contains "frills" or "sieraden".
How can i get the relevance better to match first the 2 words, then the first alone and the end only the last alone?

Besides, i try to upvote specific words like "sieraden". Is there any possiblity to get this done?

I hope someone could help me out!

Thankyou!!

Comment: have you looked at quorum syntax? ANd for "upvoting" see https://www.facebook.com/SphinxSearchServer/posts/774651362555174

Comment: Thanks i will look into it